# Get value from response collection return

Tags: laravel

I want to get the username value from this return

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "User": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "displayTest",
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "User",
        "email": "test@test.test",
        "phone_number": "01111339039",
        "date_of_birth": "1999-09-09T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "profile_picture": null,
        "default_address": {
          "id": 1,
          "user_id": 1,
          "nickname": "test",
          "address_1": "look at this road",
          "address_2": "Taman Serumah",
          "city": "Pasir Gudang",
          "postcode": "81700",
          "state": "Johor"
        },    }
  ]
```

the only thing I did is

```
$sprayer = Sprayer::findOrFail($request->sprayer_id);
return SprayerResource::collection(Sprayer::find($sprayer));
```

there are any way I can get the username value?

Comment: The `$sprayer` you passed in the `Sprayer::find($sprayer)` is i think wrong. Because the `find` method only accepts the id of the `Sprayer` not the object.

Comment: @RigelKent if you pass a model to the `find` methods it will pull the key from it (in the `whereKey` method) but there is no need to query for the same records twice like they are doing here

Comment: where in your code do you need to get this `username` property/attribute? in Javascript?